# From inside a repeaters itemtemplate, how to set a input type (image) controls title attribute?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

In my c# code, I have a constant:

```
SITE_NAME = "my site";
```

I have a repeater control, and inside the itemtemplate I have a input control:

```
<input type=image runat=server title="<%= SITE_NAME %>" />
```

Do I need special syntax to set this value?  It isn't rendering the string "my site", rather it is rending:

```
<%= SITE_NAME %>
```

i.e. it isn't parsing it as c# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working within a databound template, use <%# %> instead of <%= %>